# python demo.py /root/snowboy-master/resources/models/snowboy.umdl me da un error

Tags: linux, python-2.7, debian, raspberry-pi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error es syntaxerror:invalid syntax 
este problema me vino quando intente a usar snowboy primero no alcasava a ver snowboydetecor i qunado resolvi ese problema me vino este y busque pero no encontre nada en inernet por favor ayundeme es para la escuela.

uso debian 9 
raspberri pi3 con python 2.7.13

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0):

python training_service.py FILENAME.wav temp.wav  ciao.wav hermes.pmdl
Request failed.
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
ahora me da este problema

Answer (score -1):

Evidentemente hay un error de sintaxis en `master/examples/Python/snowboydetect.py`, pues el contenido es `../../swig/Python/snowboydetect.py` y eso en Python no es nada, simplemente un error de sintaxis. ¿Estás seguro de que ese proyecto está completo? Ese archivo Python podrías borrarlo, pues no aporta nada.